# PostgresSQL Query Issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running into an issue with a pretty complex SQL query:

```sql
SELECT u."id"
FROM "users" u
JOIN "users_rosters_schedules" urs ON u."id" = urs."user_id"
JOIN "users_postcoderegion_groups" upg ON urs."user_postcoderegion_group_id" = upg."id"
JOIN "postcode_regions" pr ON pr."id" = "users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions"."postcode_region_id"
WHERE u."role" = 'contractor'
  AND u."contractor_status" = 'active'
  AND urs."day" = '2023-12-01'
  AND urs."active" = true
  AND (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb(urs.capacity -> 'products')) AS i(item)
      WHERE (item ->> 'product_category_id')::int IN (1, 2)
        AND (item ->> 'qty')::int > (
          SELECT COUNT(o.id)
          FROM orders o
          JOIN orders_products_categories opc ON o.id = opc.order_id
          WHERE o.contractor_user_id = urs."user_id"
            AND o.status != 'cancelled'
            AND o.scheduled_pickup_date = urs."day"
            AND opc.product_category_id = CAST(i.item ->> 'product_category_id' AS INTEGER)
        )
    )
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM "users_postcoderegion_groups" upg_nested
      WHERE upg_nested."id" = urs."user_postcoderegion_group_id"
        AND EXISTS (
          SELECT *
          FROM "postcode_regions" pr_nested
          JOIN "users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions" upgrp ON pr_nested."id" = upgrp."postcode_region_id"
          WHERE pr_nested."postcode_region_id" = 8123
            AND upgrp."user_postcode_region_group_id" = upg_nested."id"
        )
    )
  )
  AND u."id" = urs."user_id";
```

When it executes, it's giving me the error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions"
> LINE 5: JOIN "postcode_regions" pr ON pr."id" = "users_postcoderegio...

Can anyone shed some light on how I could fix this?

Comment: Best guess i that this `"users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions"` is not properly defined. Either it is missing a schema prefix or the schema prefix has been folded into the quoting.

Comment: You're trying to join on `users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions.postcode_region_id` (line 5 as indicated by the error) but haven't included that table in a `JOIN` or `FROM`

Comment: users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions does exists, but way further down in your subquery

Answer (score 0):

You are joining to `users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions` but it does not exist as a joined table, it is only in a subquery and can't be accessed where you use it in `JOIN "postcode_regions" pr ON pr."id" = "users_postcoderegion_groups_postcoderegions"."postcode_region_id"`